# How do I declare and use a listbox variable Publicly?

Tags: vba, excel

Instead of writing a separate code for many listboxes (identically formatted), I am trying to use a generic code to execute an set of actions:

First, I declared the global variable in my Module names "GLOBALS":

```
Public glb As Listbox
```

In the form called "SCHEDULES" (which contains the listboxes), I have this code to set the global listbox variable when I click on the listbox:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
glb = SCHEDULE.ListBox1 <<<<<<<<<THIS IS WHERE I GET MY ERROR
End Sub
```

When I press delete, I want to call in the code called DeleteLBItem (which deletes the selected row then moves all the lower rows up:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = 46 Then
If MsgBox("Clear selected event info?", vbOKCancel, "Confirm Event Action") = vbCancel Then
Exit Sub
Else
Call DeleteLBItem
End If
End If
End Sub` `
```

The procedure DeleteLBItem is in a separate Module titles "CORE":

```
Sub DeleteLBItem()
Dim i As Integer

i = glb.ListIndex

Do Until i = glb.ListCount - 1
With glb
.List(i, 0) = .List(i + 1, 0)
.List(i, 1) = .List(i + 1, 1)
.List(i, 2) = .List(i + 1, 2)
End With
n = n + 1
Loop
With glb
.List(.ListCount, 0) = ""
.List(.ListCount, 1) = ""
.List(.ListCount, 2) = ""
End With
End Sub
```

The error I get is run time 13 (type mismatch). What do I need to do different?

Comment: Have you tried `Set glb = SCHEDULE.ListBox1`? Always delete item from the back towards the front.

Comment: Now it gives me Compile Error: Object Required

Comment: If your form is called `SCHEDULES`, shouldn't you be saying `Set glb = SCHEDULES.ListBox1`?  (i.e. add an `S` to the end of `SCHEDULE`).  (Or just say `Set glb = ListBox1` - it already knows that you are in the SCHEDULES form.)

Comment: And FWIW, you would probably be better off passing the object you want to process as a parameter to the procedure doing the work - i.e. change `Call DeleteLBItem` to `DeleteLBItem ListBox1`, and change `Sub DeleteLBItem()` to `Sub DeleteLBItem(glb as ListBox)`, and delete the `Public glb As Listbox` statement.

Comment: @YowE3K Good eye; however, I had already corrected that and I still get the same error. I tried omitting the form name as well, but still get the same error.

Comment: Although I recommend you use the approach shown in the answer from @NickSlash, your current method will probably work if you change `Public glb As ListBox` to be `Public glb As Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple listboxes (eg: LB1, LB2, LB3) and you are adding code in the events for each of those listboxes.

```
' set the global listbox to the clicked one (pseudo-code)
Private Sub LB1_Click()
GLB = LB1
End Sub
Private Sub LB2_Click()
GBL = LB2
End Sub
Private Sub LB3_Click()
GLB = LB3
End Sub
```

and you're also adding stuff to the keydown one too to execute your delete sub.

Ive not tried using a global object like that, but it doesn't seem to be working that well for you. It would be simpler to just pass a reference to the object when executing your sub.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = 46 Then
      If MsgBox("Clear selected event info?", vbOKCancel, "Confirm Event Action") = vbCancel Then
         Exit Sub
      Else
         DeleteLBItem ListBox1 ' dont need brackets here!
      End If
   End If
End Sub

Sub DeleteLBItem(ByRef LB As Object)
Dim i As Integer

   i = LB.ListIndex

   Do Until i = LB.ListCount - 1
      With LB
         .List(i, 0) = .List(i + 1, 0)
         .List(i, 1) = .List(i + 1, 1)
         .List(i, 2) = .List(i + 1, 2)
      End With
      i = i + 1 ' this was n?
   Loop
   With LB
      .List(.ListCount, 0) = ""
      .List(.ListCount, 1) = ""
      .List(.ListCount, 2) = ""
   End With
End Sub
```

I've not tested it, but assuming it works, you no longer need the code to assign the global listbox in the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

@YowE3K Thank you for the suggest. I never really understood the passing of parameters or knowingly used them, so I did some research on that and I've managed to fix the code

This code appears in the form:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 46 Then
DeleteLBItemSchedule ListBox1
Else
End If
End Sub
```

This code appears in the separate module:

```
Sub DeleteLBItemSchedule(glb As MSForms.Listbox)
Dim i As Integer
i = glb.ListIndex

Do Until i = glb.ListCount - 1
With glb
.List(i, 0) = .List(i + 1, 0)
.List(i, 1) = .List(i + 1, 1)
.List(i, 2) = .List(i + 1, 2)
End With
i = i + 1
Loop
With glb
.List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = ""
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = ""
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = ""
End With

End Sub
```